# Stretch image input and then fit to its container's width

Tags: html, css

There is a need for several images to be stretched or vice versa, compressed into one size, let's say 175 by 250 pixels.

It works like this.

```
<input type = "image" src = "@ Url.Content (topRated.Value)" onclick = "this.form.submit" class = "resize" width = "175" height = "250">

img.resize {
    width: 175 pixels;
    height: 250 pixels;
}
```

There is also a need for these images to successfully stretch-shrink when the screen is resized. Bootstrap's `.img-fluid` does a great job with this.

```
<input type = "image" alt = "Submission form" src = "@ Url.Content (topReaded.Value)" onclick = "this.form.submit" class = "img-fluid" width = "175" height = " 250 ">

.img-fluid {
  maximum width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

The question is how to make it work together? I want the images to be first stretched to a 175x250 aspect ratio, and then neatly adjusted to the parent element, as img-fluid does

Comment: It sounds like you're not interested in stretching, but in maintaining a consistent aspect ratio. Is that correct?

Comment: Also, your first CSS selector won't hit your inputs. It's targeting elements of type `img`.

Comment: @isherwood step one - stretch all images to same aspect ratio. step two - correctly resize images from parent element

Comment: I don't think you'll do that on an input without scripting. You'd need more markup to set an image element, positioned absolutely, over a container element, or you'd need to apply the image as a background, cropped to cover an element of the correct aspect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one possibility that may work, depending on your markup constraints. It uses the same zero-height/bottom padding technique that Bootstrap does for their [responsive embed feature](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/embed/#aspect-ratios):

```css
.box {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 142.85%; /* 250 ÷ 175 */
    position: relative;
}

.box input {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

/* DEMO ONLY */
.row {
  background: #f8f9fa;
  margin-top: 20px;
}

.col {
  border: solid 1px #6c757d;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      <div class="box">
        <input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x20" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      2 of 2
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col">
      1 of 3
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      <div class="box">
        <input type="image" src="https://via.placeholder.com/40x20" class="img-fluid" />
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col">
      3 of 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Fiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/isherwood/1yn3dz26/8/)

I've used oddly-sized images to demonstrate that they're being squashed into shape and stretched as requested.